# How to get dual monitors set up with ATI Radeon HD 4350 on a Dell Studio Slim?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, dell-studio

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/82460/dual-monitor-with-ati-radeon-4350) except that this is a Dell Studio Slim, so the video card only has a DVI and HDMI port, no VGA port.

Should I use a splitter on the DVI port? Or hook one monitor into DVI and the other into HDMI?

Note that the goal here is to have each monitor display a distinct image, not clone one display onto the other.

**How can I set up dual monitors on my Dell Studio Slim using an ATI Radeon HD 4350?**

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend plugging one monitor into each of the two digital outputs.

Your main monitor into the DVI and the secondary into the HDMI.

You're going to have to (if you haven't done so already) download the install AMD/ATI's desktop software from [AMD's support page.](http://support.amd.com)

With the software installed, you should be able to configure everything without problems.

EDIT: I personally don't like splitters for anything, unless the original device is configure to handle it. I'm not sure about your graphics card, but you could always check the documentation to see if the DVI port is intended for use with a splitter (some are). But still, if you have the option to plug the screens into different ports, why not make good use of it.

Comment: We connected the second monitor to the HDMI using a VGA->DVI->HDMI converter and nothing happens. Catalyst Control Center doesn't detect a second monitor. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case, your problem is most probably the converter. You might want to figure out a more 'direct' way of plugging in the screen. It seems like you're going through too many conversions.

Answer (score 0):

> We connected the second monitor to the HDMI using a VGA->DVI->HDMI

Unless you used some active (and probably not-cheap) hardware that will have work.

You have two steps here:

1. VGA (analog) to DVI (capable of analog and digital output).
2. DVI (digital) to HDMI (digital)

The plugs much match, buit without some kind of active convertor this will never work.

Solutions:

- Buy a non 1985-technology monitor (VGA is truly ancient).
- Or buy an active convertor.

Note that splitting DVI or HDMI into two cables usually does not work. (exceptions: Matrox dual head and similar, non-cheap, hardware).